# ScreenOrientation

Tags: android

Criei um `layout` e nele coloquei o seguinte codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  >
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
       android:text="Teste de Orientação"
       android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MAS quando rodo ele no emulador, e pressiono o botão 9 do teclado(para mudar de orientação) volta para outro `layout`, o de login(principal).
O que devo fazer para não dar esse tipo de erro?

Comment: Não se percebe bem o que você está perguntando. Por favor desenvolva mais a sua pergunta.

Comment: criei um layout e coloquei aquele codigo onde mostra a função para deixar apenas no modo PORTRAIT mas quando executo o app no emulador, e testo ele no modo LANDSCAPE (pressionando o botão 6 ou 9)para ver se continua no modo PORTRAIT, mas da erro no qual voltar para meu layout principal, no qual nao tem nada a ver =(

Comment: Por favor poste o código da `Activity` onde o `layout` é utilizado. Se está a dar algum erro poste também o LogCat. A informação que você deu não é suficiente para ver onde está o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente com

`android:configChanges="orientation"`

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que quando vc muda a orientação da tela a Activity é recriada.
[Veja mais sobre isso aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html%20Veja%20mais%20sobre%20isso%20aqui)

Para que isso não ocorra adicione essa linha de código no manifest do aplicativo, dentro do nó da Activity em questão:

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

Comment: adicionar aki? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.projeto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >

Comment: coloquei o codigo dentro da activity no manifest e nao deu certo, quando pressiono a tecla 9 vai para outro layout que nao tem nada haver =(

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
    android:name="br.com.exemplo.seuapp.MinhaActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_minha"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Dessa forma, na declaração da `Activity` no manifest, dentro da tag `<activity>` você consegue fazer a `Activity` funcionar apenas em `portrait`.

Contudo, o mais indicado é que você faça o tratamento da sua `Activity` e das orientações da tela.